# Plotting complex maps as z-plane and w-plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, visualization

I have seen many plots of complex maps as colors, such as $w = sin(z) = 0$:

[image: Complex color map]

However, I am looking for more involved plotting capabilities. For example I would like the ability to see the z-plane and w-plane side by side (for the map $w=f(z)$. Then I would like to be able to select a region of the z-plane and see what it got mapped to in the w-plane.

In my example above, I know that in the semi-strip: $\dfrac{-\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}, y \geq 0$ that the vertical lines get mapped to hyperbolas and the horizontal lines get mapped to elipses. It would be nice to plot this and see the semi-strip in the z-plane and its image in the w-plane.

1. What software/tools can I look into for these capabilities?

Note, that I use Sage and know a little about many programming languages (I am not afraid to customize an existing tool)

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=complex+functions&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80641/Visualizing-Complex-Functions

http://webs.um.es/gvb/AC/FC.zip

Maybe you find what you're looking in the first two links, the third is in Spanish and need Ms-Dos to run, I remember that was possible choosing strips.

But without doubt the best method is programming directly with help of some graphics library and feel the freedom of making what you need at any moment. I use to work with C and OpenGL and works really fast. You can insert parameters, modify them in real time and make what you want. That's pretty fun.

Comment: I have used c++ and OpenGL as well! So, I have some minor familiarity. Could you post some sample code showing your typical setup? I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Or where could you post your sample code is another good question...

Comment: Ok, maybe we can move to 
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math%20c%20c%2b%2b> 
Anyway I've to look for the code and clean it. Give me one day .. ;)

Comment: ¿Linux? ¿Have you made the picture above with OpenGL?

Comment: Yes I use Ubuntu Linux. I made the above plot with Sage.

Comment: Excuse the delay, i'm looking for that but this computer is an absolutly chaos, i think it's in another disk, but don't worry i'll find it, sorry again. Regards

Comment: Hey, did you ever find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The [conformal](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots/conformal) command of Maple is it. Also [complexplot](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots/complexplot) and [complexplot3d](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots/complexplot3d) and [transform](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plottools/transform) may be useful.

PS. For example, the command $$plots:-conformal(sin(z), z = -(1/2)*Pi .. (1/2)*Pi+2*I, grid = [8, 8], numxy = [50, 50]) $$ produces 
[image]